# url rewriting in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to serve different urls using mod_rewrite but whatever I try it is just not working.

An example url would be 
http://www.site.com/country/tours/dynamic-part/?&city=new-york,los-angeles

And I am trying to change the url using .htaccess to:

http://www.site.com/country/tours/dynamic-part/new-york,los-angeles

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)city=([^&]*)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^country\/tours\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\/.+city=([^\/]*)$ http://www.site.com/country/tours/$1/$2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas? I though I was close but not anymore :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RewriteRule does NOT match the query string, see
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what_is_matched

So the `.+city` part of the rule will never match.

This should work tho...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)city=([^&]*)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^country\/tours\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\/ http://www.site.com/country/tours/$1/%2 [L,R=301]
```

The subsitution can read back-referenecs to the RewriteCond pattern.

Comment: I put it in my .htaccess (It doesn't return 500 internal server error like my modifications did) but it doesn't remove the city parameter. I am using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test my htaccess.

Comment: Check your error log to find what it doesnt like about the file. And how do you know that site is reliable. Another interesting point is your 'dynamic part' example contains a hyphen, but that is not in your regular expression. You might want qsdiscard too.